# (MS Excel) Do you know a way of putting equation into cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, spreadsheet

I would like to achieve following as my spreadsheet is rather large and I always spend a lot of time figuring out some of my calculations that I made few weeks ago.

Just by looking at the formula, I cannot really say, which equation / correlation was used. Notes such as *"this guys" (1967) for "some" ratio < "something" and ___ < "something"* are also not as clear as putting equation next to it. If I cannot put it in a cell, it usually gets disarranged. Is there any trick.

Example of what I want to achieve (This was made in Numbers, which are otherwise inferior to MS Excel):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various 3rd party 'add-in' providers that you can utilise to assist with this (I used MathType for my MSc dissertation which included over 100 equations in tables etc.).

You can also use this to easily prepare a neatly aligned set of equations in MS Word (where I imagine your table is ultimately going, if not in Latex - although I could be wrong!).

To snap any object to a cell boundary, hold alt whist dragging it with your mouse in MS Excel.

To resize the object ensure you select "lock aspect ratio" to avoid undue distortion (equation objects need extra TLC as an incorrect aspect ratio for your equation can detract from credibility of your overall work!

---

jOptoins**
[image: Options:Aadvised before resizing picture equation]

---

**Sample**

[image: Table of equations prepared in MS-Word (©)]

Comment: I use Equation Maker which I would expect is very similar to MathType. I can export the formula as either image or .pdf. However, I cannot "snap" this formula to a cell in MS Excel. So, all of the formulas are put in the sheet as "non snappable" object. As in Numbers I can paste image/.pdf directly to one cell. Is MathType any different?

Comment: Ahhh - I see what you mean... I generally insert the equation then hold alt while I move it with my mouse, that will auto-align it with the adjacent vertical or horizontal cell boundary of the closest cell (similar to snapping),  If I want to resize it, I ensure 'fix aspect ratio' option is turned on (right click equation, and view picture properties in right pane that pops up).  Note - excel also has a native formula editor.  The best way I have found to do what I think you're trying to do is to make a table in MS Word, then align the equations as req. in that setting...

Comment: Have updated my soln - if this works for you don't forget to upvote! ta

Comment: Thanks! In such way the organization definitely improved (I was not aware about the "alt hold" function). Combining MS Word and MS Excel would not me progressive in my case as my goal is not to get a good-looking table, but rather a clean design. Still, the Numbers are better for this specific case. It is a pity that they are worst in other 100 cases... :-).

Answer (score 1):

You of course can add a comment or note to the cell by Right-Clicking the cell.

If you want to include a comment in the formula itself...

[image]

HTH

Comment: I don't see how could I put formula I showed as an example in such form, substituting ("This is a Comment").

Comment: Josh, you are correct. Unfortunately, this is a limitation of all of the Excel methods for commenting cells AFAICT. HTH